# How to get a file object from the content:// scheme in android pie?

Tags: android, uri, android-9.0-pie

I have this code that stores a path of an image file in a local database which is like this "content://media/external/images/media/25" which was returned when selecting an image from the device's internal storage running Android Pie.

Now, when I try to create a File object from the above content path, it throws FileNotFoundException.

```
val imagePath = URL("content://media/external/images/media/25")
val imageFile = File(imagePath)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. Use `Uri.parse()` to parse your string into a `Uri` and pass that `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso. Note that [you may not have rights to access the content anymore](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: I understand that `Uri ` is not a file and had used `Uri.prase()` which gives `"external/images/media/25"` as in `imageFile = File(Uri.parse(ImagePath))`, but this also results in FileNotFoundException.  And I am using the File object for getting ExifInfo,  'val exif = ExifInterface( imageFile.absolutePath)'  and not  to load in an imageview for now.

Comment: "I understand that Uri is not a file" -- then why do you do things like `imageFile = File(Uri.parse(ImagePath))`? " And I am using the File object for getting ExifInfo" -- open an `InputStream` on the content using a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. Pass that to the `ExifInterface` constructor. Make sure that you are using the `ExifInterface` from the Jetpack, not the framework one, which has security bugs on older devices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will try this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ContentUris

```
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id);
File file =new File(contentUri)
```